# Translating “profile” and “area of specialisation” on a CV

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate my CV into German and to find appropriate expression for the following:

- *profile* (e.g. graduate engineer, bachelor, master)
- *area of specialisation*

Regarding the first expression, *Studiengang* sounds suitable to me. 
In connection with the second one, is it possible that *Spezialisierungsbereich* is appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to say that *profile* is the highest degree you've achieved, I would translate *profile* as *Abschluss*. If you want to tell which schools you've visited in chronological order, *profile* translates to *Bildungsweg*.

I would translate *area of specialisation* as *Fachgebiet*. You could then elaborate the *Fachgebiet* in the description, like

> Fachgebiet: Netzwerktechnik, speziell: Glasfaseranbindungen

Comment: Instead of "Fachgebiet" I would recommend "Vertiefungsrichtung" because "Fachgebiet" is too broad for what Marina is trying to achieve. Since different courses of studies are composing a "Fachgebiet".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact purpose *Spezialisierungsbereich* can be correct.

But I my understanding of this term is, as native German speaker, that it's a further description of another area of specialization.
For example, the term *computer scientist* is very broad. Further *Spezialisierungsbereich* could be *Web-communication* or *Operating systems*, but IT itself is more of a *Fachgebiet* than a *Spezialisierungsbereich*.

What I mean: There are plenty of *Fachgebiete* like *Medizin*, *Ingenieurwesen*, *Betriebswirtschaftslehre*,... and every *Fachgebiet* could be subdivided into several *Spezialisierungsbereiche*.

The common term of a *Studiengang* is not *Spezialisierungsbereich* but *Fachgebiet* and *Spezialisierungsbereich* depends on the assamble of lectures you are visiting, not the "subject" , which represents the *Fachgebiet*, you are studying.

Comment: Fixed some typos, but what is "assamble"? There are the words "assembly" and to "to assemble" but both do not make sense.

Comment: @Em1...maybe "sample", but probably "col-/selection"